# Create object from Firebase Document with complex types and DocumentReferences

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying to figure out a cleaner way to create custom `Swift` objects using `Firebase` and the `Identifiable, Codable` interfaces.

I have:

```swift
struct Post: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?

    var foodItem: FoodItem

    var chef: Chef
    var title: String

    var date: Date

    init(id: String?, foodItem: FoodItem, chef: Chef, title: String, date: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.foodItem = foodItem
        self.chef = chef
        self.title = title
        self.date = date
    }
}
```

If I try to do `document?.data(as: Post.self)`, it will not load because it cannot properly create the nested complex types, `FoodItem` and `Chef`.

On `Firebase`, each type is stored as a separate collection.

`posts` contains `Post` with the simple types as fields but it references `FoodItem` and `Chef` to their own collection documents.

As a result, when reading the `document.()`, for `.foodItem` and `.chef`, I get back `DocumentReference` which requires me to further do `DocumentReference.getDocument()` to get the actual data. This means, the automatic decoder doesn't work.

Is there a way to write a custom decoder to factor in that the keys for `FoodItem` and `Chef` will not be the right objects but will come in as `DocumentReference`s requiring further action? And how should this be handled? I do not want to have to decode in the `Post` model which will include code to read from the server.

I'm just trying to avoid having to load each field one by one and having long, messy constructors such as... `Post(id: id, foodItem: foodItem, chef: chef, title: title, date: date)` and similar ones for `Chef`, `FoodItem`, etc.

Comment: Are you saying that in Firestore, there's a collection of Post documents. Within each Post document there's a collection of FoodItem and Chef or are FoodItem and Chef not stored within the Post document? e.g. they are collections OUTSIDE of the Post document? If it's the latter then the only option will be to read them separately once the Post is read and you know the reference path to the FoodItem and Chef

Comment: Yes exactly.

I am trying to read them separately and I do get the results back that way - I can successfully create a `FoodItem` once I get the document using the `Post`'s document reference to `FoodItem`.

Comment: I am more wondering - is there a way that after I get the individual nested items through their own document references (I'm using `GroupDispatch` to ensure I have all the information ready at the end), I can call a custom or existing decoder passing in these prepared items with the proper keys and let it do the rest of the work, rather than having to manually call an `init()` by also getting the other simple keys?

Comment: Not sure I am clear on this. Are you asking if you can perform a query on a collection but have the query return results (for a different object) from a totally separate collection?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Codable Struct that matches the fields in firebase? For this to work you'll need top import "FirebaseFirestoreSwift in the file you're declaring your struct in.

```
struct Post: Codable {
var foodItem: FoodItem
var chef: Chef
var title: String
var date: Date

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case foodItem
    case chef
    case title
    case date
}
```

}

You can then create a function that gets the documentSnapshot and transforms it to a struct. For example:

```
func getFirebaseObject(document: DocumentSnapshot, completion: @escaping(GroupStructure) -> Void) {
    let result = Result {
        try document.data(as: Post.self)
    }
    
    switch result {
    case .success(let response):
        if let response = response {
            completion(response)
        } else {
            print("Document Doesnt exist")
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

You can then get the document and transform it to an object like this:

```
let dbRef = Firestore.firestore().colletion("x").document("y")
dbRef.getDocument {(document, error) in 
   if let document = document {
      getFirebaseObject(document) { (structure) in
        print(structure.chef)
     }
   }
}
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I did that and it would work in a normal circumstance but the uniqueness of this situation is how the Firebase collections are setup.

`Posts` has it's own collection with some documents. Those documents reference `Chef` and `FoodItem` which are in their OWN collections and documents. So in the `Posts`, we have a `DocumentReference` to the other documents, hence the decoder gets confused as it cannot convert a `DocumentReference` to say, a `Chef`.